# R: Remove vector elements based on matrix value

Tags: r

I have a vector of elements similar to this one:

`Sentences -> c("Sentence_1", "Sentence_2", "Sentence_3", "Sentence_4")`

And I have also a matrix where the rows and columns are formed by each element in `Sentences`:

```
          Sentence_1   Sentence_2   Sentence_3   Sentence_4
Sentence_1    1           0.25         0.74         0.35
Sentence_2   0.25           1          0.36         0.82
Sentence_3   0.74         0.36           1          0.12
Sentence_4   0.35         0.82         0.12           1
```

What I need is to check the values of the matrix for each pair of elements, find those with a value higher than 0.7 and remove one of the elements of that pair from `Sentences`.

In the example above, `Sentence_1` and `Sentence_3` have a value of 0.74, I'd want to remove `Sentence_3`. The same happens with `Sentence_2` and `Sentence_4` have a value of 0.82, so I'd want to remove `Sentence_4`.

My final `Sentences` vector would be `Sentences -> c("Sentence_1", "Sentence_2")`

Is there a direct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this :

```
#Create a copy of matrix
copy_mat <- mat
#Set values to NA where value is greater than 0.7
copy_mat[upper.tri(copy_mat)][copy_mat[upper.tri(copy_mat)] > 0.7] <- NA
#Remove NA value columns from Sentences
setdiff(Sentences, colnames(copy_mat)[colSums(is.na(copy_mat)) > 0])
#[1] "Sentence_1" "Sentence_2"
```

In this answer I compare the upper triangular values, since you have a symmetric matrix you can do the same with lower triangular and get another pair as answer (`"Sentence_3"`, `"Sentence_4"`).